# FTP connection and upload under proxy using command prompt and Putty

Tags: vba, proxy, ftp, putty

I have a small access database which makes CSV file that should be uploaded on a remote FTP server.

I need to make automated process to upload a file using command prompt (which I access through VBA shell).

Issue is that I can access internet only via proxy, and can't seem to find any resource online on how to set up putty (proxy connection) and upload the file.

Any help is highly appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: If you are on Windows you may want to consider a socks proxy application like FreeCap or Hummingbird Socks which would run on your PC. That would then start an application and redirect all TCP calls through a SOCKS proxy of your choice.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a Unix guy, so forgive my slant.

I use the scp command along with a decked out .ssh/config file.

Putty has the pscp.exe command that I believe works similar.

http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html

Here is the link to Putty's proxy config panel
http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.60/htmldoc/Chapter4.html#config-proxy

Comment: thnx for the info. will try something similar!